# Trying to add SASS to a React application

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I created a brand new React application with `create-react-app` and now I want to add SASS to it.

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc). Basically I run

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

and then added these two lines to my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass src/ -o src/", # Line 1
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive", # Line 2
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

This should do the job, according to the documentation, but when I complete the process doing

```
mv src/App.css src/App.scss
```

and then

```
npm run watch-css
```

the script just won't finish by itself. I always have to use `Ctrl-C` to finish it and I believe this is not normal.

My questions are:

- Is this normal?
- Have I missed something?
- If so, what have I missed?

Comment: You running watch-css, the script won't finish by itself because he watching for sass file changes. every change will run the preprocessor.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks! It is a watcher in the full sense of the word. Keeps watching for changes in my scss files.

Comment: By the documentation I (wrongly) imagined it would "compile" SASS to CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transpile the `scss` to `css` for this you can use `Webpack` or `Gulp`. I will show you an example for `Webpack` as I prefer this more. Webpack it takes a while to config you can watch tons of internet tutorials.

In order to `transpile scss into css` you need to write a `loader`, in `Webpack` will be something like this:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
            'style', 'css!sass'
        )
      },
    ]
  },
```

This are the packages for the loader, `install with npm --S -D sass-loader style-loader` into `package.json` file.

Now in order for `Webpack` to see the `scss` files you need to import those files into a `js/jsx` file for example `App.jsx`. But to not have a lot of imports you can have a `base.scss` and you will import other `scss` fils into it

example `import './assets/stylesheets/scss/base.scss';`

*`base.scss` contains `import` to other `scss` files.*

This is just a small introduction to what you must do. You need a little bit more to config `Webpack` you can search on `youtube` for that or [This github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) link will help you alot!

`Gulp` is similar you write `tasks`, as far as I know there is `gulp-scss` package.